# Azure Point to Site Connection to On Premise SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I have an Azure Website that I have recently set up a point to site connection for.  The purpose of the connection was to connect to an on-premise SQL server.  The connection appears to be connected and working via the Windows Azure Management portal.  I see that traffic is very light, which is not right given the volume of data that was being pushed, which leads me to believe the traffic is not getting routed through the new VPN connection.

My question is this.  Do I need to modify the Server address in my connection string in the cloud configuration file to reflect the new "Local" IP Address of the virtual network I just set up?  It seems logical, but I did not see this step in the directions I followed on:  https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

Thanks for your help.